# Java Platform, Micro Edition Software Development Kit 3.0 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I tried to install the Java Platform, Micro Edition Software Development Kit 3.0 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-javame-downloads.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR) but the install wizard gave me this error:

```
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.608]: loading sdk library
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.609]:     library resource path: native/jmesdk/windows/windows-x86.dll
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.612]:     library file path: C:\Users\Owen\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-5419155011880735000.tmp
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.646]:     Cannot load native library from path: native/jmesdk/windows/windows-x86.dll
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.664]:     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Owen\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-5419155011880735000.tmp: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.664]:      at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.664]:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.664]:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.664]:      at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.665]:      at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.665]:      at org.netbeans.installer.utils.system.j2mesdk.SDKExtraUtils.loadNativeLibrary(SDKExtraUtils.java:128)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.665]:      at org.netbeans.installer.utils.system.j2mesdk.SDKExtraUtils.<clinit>(SDKExtraUtils.java:42)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.665]:      at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.actions.j2mesdk.IsProductInstalledAction.execute(IsProductInstalledAction.java:94)
[2020-08-18 13:04:55.665]:      at org.netbeans.installer.wizard.components.WizardAction$1.run(WizardAction.java:120)
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not downloading the [latest version](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/sdk-downloads.html)?

Comment: @Abra Oh jeez, I didn't know it was outdated. I was redirected from this: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/sun-java-wireless-toolkit.html